# Multi domain routing in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5

I have setup multi-domain routing in my laravel 5.2 app. What I want to achieve is if a user hits, membership.app, he should be served different homepage as compared to user who hits, erp.app domain.

```
Route::pattern('erp', 'erp.app|erp.domain.com');
Route::pattern('membership', 'membership.app|membership.domain.com');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth'], 'domain' => '{erp}'], function() {
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@getIndex');
    Route::controller('members', 'MembersController');
    Route::controller('users', 'UsersController');
    Route::controller('settings', 'SettingsController');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'web', 'domain' => '{erp}'], function () {
    Route::controller('auth', 'Auth\AuthController');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'web', 'domain' => '{membership}'], function () {
    Route::controller('/', 'BecomeMemberController');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::controller('ajax', 'AjaxController');
});
```

I tried this setup, but it breaks the code with first param in each controller method being the url instead of intended value.

Suppose I have a method `hello` in `members` controller.

```
public function hello($param1, $param2)
{
    ....
}
```

If I access `erp.app/members/hello/1/2` url and try to print out `$param1` of controller method, it returns `erp.app` instead of intended `1` in this case.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why aren't you seperating the routes to different controllers as you say the output will be quite different...

A quick example of to use that:

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{type}.myapp.com'], function () {

Route::get('members/hello/{id1}/{id2}', function ($type, $id1, $id2) {

        // when you enter --> members.myapp.com/hello/12/45

        var_dump($type); //memebers
        var_dump($id1); //12
        var_dump($id2); //45
    });

});
```